# Filter Array by property

Tags: php, arrays, filter

How can I filter this array in PHP so it only contains entries where `[is_published] = 1`?

I've been looking on Stack Overflow all afternoon and have tried `filter_array` and other methods but I just can't get it right...

```
FB_manager_array2: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 244987165675334
                            [is_published] => 1
                            [name] => Zitecraft.com
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 437060646380356
                            [is_published] => 1
                            [name] => Beauty & care Alexandra
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 663302210366640
                            [is_published] => 1
                            [name] => Tiramisu Gelato ijssalon
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 295426223953905
                            [is_published] => 1
                            [name] => Ck's Hairstyling
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 213820525062
                            [is_published] => 1
                            [name] => Citynumbers.com - Feel like going out tonight?
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 114373308748798
                            [is_published] => 1
                            [name] => YOLO: You Only Live Once
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 200408800066160
                            [is_published] => 
                            [name] => Citynumbers Social Widget
                        )

                )

            [paging] => Array
                (
                    [cursors] => Array
                        (
                            [before] => MjQ0OTg3MTY1Njc1MzM0
                            [after] => MjAwNDA4ODAwMDY2MTYw
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

With [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$FB_manager_array2[0]['data'] = array_filter($FB_manager_array2[0]['data'], function($v) {
    return $v['is_published'] == '1';
});
```